# How do you reheat rice in a takeout box after you've already made the mistake of refrigerating it straight up?

Tags: rice, culinary-uses

I have refrigerated rice that I want to serve alongside chicken tikka masala (Not for guests, that's unthinkable! For family.). It's in one of those styrofoam containers with a plastic lid, although it's hard and, in present state, unappetizing all the same, so let's benefit Googlers by assuming a takeout box. There's plenty of stuff on the net on how to store it properly in the first place. **How do you revive hard refrigerated rice after the fact?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming it's been kept cold & is therefore 'safe', then just drop it into a larger microwave-safe dish with a not-quite-sealed lid & maybe a tablespoon of cold water.

Once it's halfway heated, you'll be able to break it up a bit to stir. When fully heated, it will break up with a fork. Your family will never know ;)

Comment: This is what I do. If it's really really hard, I'll add more water and let it steam until all the liquid has been absorbed into the rice.